# Acrobat digital signature -mark as read only not working

Tags: adobe-acrobat, digital-signature

I am using Acrobat XI Pro.  I have created a simple form where the top half should be filled in then digitally signed by user 1.  Then the bottom half should be filled by user 2, but user 2 should not be able to edit anything in the top half of the form.

I have completed the form and have a digital signature field.  At the digital signature field, I go to  >properties>signed tab>mark as read only>just these fields.   When I click to select the fields I want to restrict, they don’t check. I can “select all” and then they all check, but if I click to un-check specific ones, they don’t un-check either.

I have spent hours searching user forums and have found this question asked but no one presents an answer.  The only suggestion posed is at the Adobe site, which states to check fields for spaces and punctuation.  I have looked at my field names, and there is no punctuation and there are no spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the space bar to select the fields rather than trying to use the mouse.